# como usar 2 diferentes look and feel diferentes

Tags: java, java-swing, interfaz-gráfica, jframe, ventana

buenas noches estoy aprendiendo java y  tengo un proyecto donde debo usar 1 ventana principar y 3 ventanas secundarias al implentar un look and feel el la principal las demas ventanas reciben la misma apariencia.

si escribo en el main de la principal:

```
try {
        UIManager.setLookAndFeel("com.jtattoo.plaf.luna.LunaLookAndFeel");
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex)
```

y si escribo en el main de la secundaria:

```
try {
        UIManager.setLookAndFeel("com.jtattoo.plaf.aero.aeroLookAndFeel");
        
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex)
```

no se aplica el nuevo look and feel en la ventana secundaria. alguien me puede orientar en la implementacion de los look and feel es un tema nuevo para mi. gracias

Answer (score 0):

Para que un LAF sea aplicado en la interfaz, debes establecerlo antes de ejecutar ninguna operación con los objetos Swing. ¿Te aseguraste de no haber inicializado los componentes antes de establecer el nuevo LAF?